# How to remove this old kernel?

Tags: kernel, purge

When I try to autoremove, I get these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 161 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 334755 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-51-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-51-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_wocXOB/lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_wocXOB/lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo 4.4.0-51-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
Fatal: open /dev/disk/by-id/: Is a directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Would you see a way for me to remove the trace of kernel 4.4.0 in my system? (I recently updated to 8)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that you manually removed some kernel files. You need to re-install that kernel and then remove it.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/623687/225694

Comment: Sorry it didn't work impossible to install the package